# Site Collections Search not working

Tags: search, sharepoint-search

On our Intranet landing page search is configured and it is working, but under Site Collections that have their own content database, the search returns no results.

How can I configure search to work under those Site Collections.

Comment: Are you sure that your content sources is crawling the subsites and no only the portal?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Search Account used for content crawling. The account  needs to have read access to the site collections and its databases. To do so open your Central Administration => Application Management => Manage Web Applications => Select Web Application of Site Collection which is not crawled correctly => User Policy => If Content Crawl Account is not listed here, add it.

If this does not solve your problem, check the Crawl Logs in Central Administration => Application Management => Manage Service Applications => Your Search Service Application => Crawl Log. Check the error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions below. i will test them as come back if it works.

Comment: Stal1402, i tried using the second sentence and i am getting Sorry, something went wrong . i cannot open the Crawl log

Comment: Siphesakhe, please review your ULS log. You will find it on your server in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

Comment: Hi Stal1402. Thank you for assisting me until now. i have located the folder mentioned above. what must i look for inside the LOGS folder?

Comment: Usually you get a correlation ID with an error message. In your case with the "Sorry, something went wrong" message you should have a link "Details" below. Click it to get the correlation ID. Find the log file which is covering the corresponding time period and search for the correlation ID.
You can also download ULS Viewer to simplify the handling of ULS logs: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020)